# reading 3 integers in one line java

Tags: java

help me finding a way to read from user 3 integers in one line and then treat each saparately as a,b,c .. please be quick because i had tried reading a whole line but i want to deal with each integer in later statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MHDKhaledTotonji_301300797 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int M,a,b,c;
        System.out.println("Please, insert the normal dose in ml");
        M = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take them as comma separated values and then try to split and parse. Easy.

Comment: Why comma-separated? Space-separated is more user-friendly here. (My opinion anyway)

Answer (score 3):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = in.nextInt();
    int b = in.nextInt();
    int c = in.nextInt();
```

takes: 1 2 3

Comment: Doesn't force user to type all 3 on one line, and will crash the program on bad input, but it's an easy solution that gets the job done.

Comment: thank u but tell me what can i do if i want the user to enter 3 integers as much as he needs in one line (3 ints per line) and when he needs to stop put 0 0 0

Answer (score 2):

`nextLine()` returns a `String`, so `M` should be defined as a `String`.

Java naming conventions generally state that variables should start with lowercase letter, so `M` should be `m`.

As for the task of getting 3 integers from the user on one line, you have multiple choices, and it depends on how strict you want to be and how much error handling you need.

1. For very easy solution, with no error handling (kills program on bad input), `Scanner` is the answer. Error handling can be added, but is cumbersome.

   ```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please, insert the normal dose in ml");
   int a = input.nextInt();
   int b = input.nextInt();
   int c = input.nextInt();
   ```
2. Another solution might be to read the line, like you are trying to do, then split the line and parse the values. A little more code, but forces user to enter all 3 on one line, which solution #1 doesn't.

   ```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please, insert the normal dose in ml");
   String line = input.nextLine();
   String[] values = line.split(" ");
   int a = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
   int b = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
   int c = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
   ```
3. For better control of the line from the user, a regular expression can be used. Here it is with full error handling.

   ```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*");
   int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
   for (;;) {
       System.out.println("Please, insert the normal dose in ml");
       String line = input.nextLine();
       Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
       if (m.matches())
           try {
               a = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
               b = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
               c = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
               break;
           } catch (Exception e) {/*fall thru to print error message*/}
       System.out.println("** Bad input. Type 3 numbers on one line, separated by space");
   }
   ```

Comment: omg thank u ur very helpfull dude

Comment: @JeenzooKT Click the up-arrow on answers you find useful. Click the check mark for a single answer that you find acceptable, so others can see that your question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

use `input.nextInt()` instead of `input.nextLine()`. Also this is wrong because `input.nextLine()` returns `String` and you should `parse` to `integer`.

Simple change your code to:

```
M = input.nextInt();
a = input.nextInt();
b = input.nextInt();
c = input.nextInt();
```

Stick in mind that `input.nextInt()` ignores every white space including line feeds so you don't need to worry about reading from the same or different lines.

Comment: thanks man !! tell me what can i do if i want to take the sum of each line the user puts and deal with it in a later statement

Comment: The above solution works in every case.
You should only use `input.nextInt()` each time you want to take an integer, regardless of number of lines.